# Why do I get "Error: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1." from xsd utility

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, xml-parsing

I want to be able to scan SSRS report definition (.rdl) files and alter them programmatically.  I am following a Microsoft tutorial (albeit a little out-of-date but can't find an up-to-date version).

The tutorial is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/aa337455(v%3dsql.90)

I have downloaded the XML Schema File from the Microsoft website - ReportDefinition.xsd - and am now following the steps 4 to 6 that say to open the Visual Studio Command Prompt and run the utility XSD to generate the ReportDefinition.vb file that contains the classes for the RDL schema.

However, when I run the command as per the instructions:

```
xsd /c /l:VB /n:SampleRDLSchema ReportDefinition.xsd
```

... I simply get the error message:

```
Error: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.
```

This is the first few lines of the file; I can't see the characters 0x00 the error message refers to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft.  All rights reserved. -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>

        The following schema describes the structure of the 
      Report Definition Language (RDL) for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.
```

Given this is a Microsoft written set of instructions to use a Microsoft utility running against a Microsoft supplied file, I'm a bit baffled as to why there should be an error in it.

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue being reported at the start of line 2 could indicate that this is an encoding issue. The attribute `encoding="utf-8"` on the first line indicates that the file should be interpreted as having a a UTF-8 encoding. So after the first line, the xsd utitlity would try to read the file as UTF-8. If the file actually uses a different encoding, then an error would be produced like the one you have encountered.

To test this, remove `encoding="utf-8"` from the first line & run the command again.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I downloaded another copy of the document from the Microsoft site and the problem went away.  Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was another issue. My file contained some includes like :

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="XMLFILE.xsd"/>
```

So the error meaning is "it cannot find the XMLFILE.xsd". Make sure you have all related xml files from all includes in all files. You know it when you right clicking on the file in visual studio and do "View Code (F7)". If the include is underlined in red, the file is missing or something in the "XMLFile.xsd" is missing.

***Please Microsoft's crew, showing a clear error message can save us a ton of hours of works... Don't you?***